# Can't set fg or foreground of a ttk.Checkbutton

Tags: python, ttk

On instantiating a ttk.Checkbutton with some kwargs. One of the kwargs is `foreground`, I'm getting `TclError: unknown option "-foreground"`. It works if I remove `foreground`.

Here's the line of code and the values just before the call as seen in PyCharm...

[image: Pycharm Debug]

`widget` is a `ttk.Checkbutton`. Here's the error...

```
  File "...widget.py", line 76, in add_widget_and_position
    **widget_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 633, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'ttk::checkbutton', kw)
    |               |     |                           -> {'foreground': 'purple', 'text': u'Free to air', 'width': None, 'state': 'normal', 'command':  at 0x04881970>,...
    |               |     -> 
    |               -> 
    -> 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 555, in __init__
    Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
    |                       |     |       |              -> {'foreground': 'purple', 'text': u'Free to air', 'width': None, 'state': 'normal', 'command':  at 0x04881970>,...
    |                       |     |       -> 'ttk::checkbutton'
    |                       |     -> 
    |                       -> 
    -> 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2091, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: unknown option "-foreground"
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  Hopefully it's simple and stupid :/

Comment: According to this page: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Checkbutton.html `ttk.Checkbutton` does not inherit the foreground option. You must configure it using a style.

Comment: Thanks. Simple and stupid it is! Puzzled that something similar appears to be working in the code I'm massively refactoring, and now I can see that he's not using ttk.Checkbutton, it's a Tkinter.Checkbutton.